# One Web Request Processed by two Worker Process

Tags: web, iis-7, w3wp, worker-process, web-garden

I am configuring a web garden in IIS server.

I know that the web garden will have more than once worker process for a application pool, which mean that extra w3wp.exe can get created for one web application once it's number of requests exceeds the limit. (Please correct me if i am wrong)

From the above case , is there a possibility for one request is being processed by more than one w3wp.exe ?

and also need clarity on whether two w3wp.exe will be created for single application? or two w3wp.exe will share the applications in an app pool.

Answer (score 1):

> From the above case , is there a possibility for one request is being processed by more than one w3wp.exe ?

No, each request is assigned to one and only one worker process.

> whether two w3wp.exe will be created for single application? or two w3wp.exe will share the applications in an app pool.

Two (or more) worker processes will be created for the application pool. Inside the pool you can have multiple applications or App-Domains in Dot.net terms. If you have multiple applications in the pool, requests for each application are distributed among the processes. So with two applications and two W3wps you can't tell which w3sp processes the request for a specific application.